# Akamai EAA with WSL - no DNS resolution

Tags: windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux

The company I work for is using Akamai Enterprise Application Access (EAA) instead of a traditional VPN. When using WSL 2 in Windows, no hostnames are getting resovled via DNS.
The contents of the auto-generated `/etc/resolv.conf` are

```
# This file was automatically generated by WSL. To stop automatic generation of this file, add the following entry to /etc/wsl.conf:
# [network]
# generateResolvConf = false
nameserver 192.168.86.1
nameserver 127.50.100.1
search lan
```

(these are the DNS IPs from "normal" Windows)

I'm not exactly sure how EAA handles DNS, but it works in "normal" Windows but not in WSL. Is there a way to get DNS working with WSL and EAA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I thought I was using WSL 2, the distribution I had was running under WSL 1.

Running `wsl -l -v` in Windows confirmed this.

I used `wsl --set-version [my distribution name] 2` to upgrade it to WSL 2.

This changed the contents of the `/etc/resolv.conf` file - it looks like WSL isn't proxying network requests through local Windows addresses any more.

Anyway, with a WSL 2 distribution, I don't have any issues resolving hosts, internal or external.